# Create Sharepoint Folder using Access VBA

Tags: sharepoint-online, access

I am trying to write VBA code in Access to check if folder exists on Sharepoint site and if it doesn't the create it, if it does then just open a location of it.

I managed to get it to open existing ones using some of my old codes, but can't figure out how to make it work to create and check for existing.

Help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no VBA that can be used to create folders in SharePoint online. VBA does not have commands for that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround you can try, make the SharePoint library sync to local folders, then use the VBA code to manage the local folders. OneDrive would do the syncing work and finally you can have similar functionalities.